# The method setFragment(Fragment) in the type FacebookButtonBase is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment)

Tags: android, fragment

I am getting an error on line loginbutton.setfragment(this) so I removed the
import android.app.Activity; and used v4.app.Fragment instead but now I am getting error at .add() line in MainActivity. please somebody tell me what to do

```
 import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            LoginButton loginbutton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginbutton.setFragment(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but now I am getting error at .add() line in MainActivity. please
>   somebody tell me what to do

extend one between `AppCompatActivity` and `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`, and use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`